# Facebook graph app requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I dont know why but `https://graph.facebook.com/132333806850364?access_token=218237124854683|VLsQV-ec2paQpq5hVMFFjtnk9_w` returns false even though the app token is valid. The invitation was sent properly and I recieve invitations as well.

```
   //Single user REquest
       function sendRequestSingle(c_id,page_id,sendto,from,g_id) {  
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            to: sendto,
            message: 'Win Mega Prizes!',
            title: 'Enter in this contest!',
            data: c_id+','+page_id+','+g_id
        },
        function (response) {   
           if (response && response.request_ids) {
               var requests = response.request_ids;
                    window.location.href = "http://www.serverhere.com/contest/handle_invitations.php?invitations="+requests+"&contest_id="+c_id+"&page_id="+page_id+"&user="+from+"&g_id="+g_id+"&sendto="+sendto+"&single=1";         

            } else {
                alert('canceled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```